# Mongoose populate subdocs with condition and update those

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a problem regarding updating my `UserModel` subdocument which is `(OfferModel)`

```
const user = Schema({
  name: String,
  offers: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Offer'
  }]
});

const offer = Schema({
  title: String,
  post: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  },
  buyer: {
    deal: String,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  },
  seller: {
    deal: String,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }
});
```

So here's the situation
I have a user who has 3 offers on 1 post but a total of 10 offers as a whole

```
Post A = 3 offers.
Post B = 7 offers.
```

Then I accepted one offer on post A, so i query the database and make the "deal" property under "buyer" to be set to "ok", there's no problem with that. Now i need to set "rejected" to the other 2 offers on the Post A.
There's a solution for this if i do the Javascript way:

1. Get the Post Id
2. Populate the offers under User model, use match operator to only get offers on the specific post & that hasn't been confirmed (which is 2 offers)
3. iterate through them and just assign `user.offers.buyer.deal = "rejected"`
4. Save()

With this approach it's fine, but i want to do it in Mongoose way, i just want to know how can i do it in mongoose way?

I've also checked the `.update()` operator, but I can't seem to make it work properly or it's not the thing that i need.

Any inputs on how can I update those 2 offers using just only Mongoose operators?

Thank you

**Update

```
const user = await this.userRepo.findUser(req.user._id)
  .select('offers')
  .populate({
    path: 'offers',
    match: {
      post: req.body.postId,
      'buyer.feedback': 'none'
    }
  })
  .update({}, {
    '$set': {
      'offers.$.buyer.feedback': 'ok'
    }
  });
```

Error `CastError : Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ok" at path "offers"`

***Update 2 Sample Docs
****Update 3 before and after

```
// John
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee2a8"),
  "name": "john",
  "offers": [
    ObjectId("5ad2aac1b0ef21131439223c"), // Offer that i accepted
    ObjectId("5ad2ab39b0ef21131439223d"), // Offer i should reject
    ObjectId("5ad2b9b2751c39321c4173e4"), // Offer i should reject
    ObjectId("5ad2d0846778d91eb0b109a8"),
    ObjectId("5ad2d136e50e903240cdb4b9"),
    ObjectId("5ad2d14ae50e903240cdb4ba"),
    ObjectId("5ad2d2acde95b51e205b26fc"),
    ObjectId("5ad9cbaec9c10314148adcd8"),
    ObjectId("5ad9ccf60c7f492940d4bd9d"),
    ObjectId("5ad9cd2e0c7f492940d4bd9e"),
  ],
  "post": [
    ObjectId("5abf4eb433063a3ebc8ba78f"), // Post A
    ObjectId("5abf4ec533063a3ebc8ba790"),
  ]
};

// Offer that i accepted
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ad2aac1b0ef21131439223c"),
    "buyer" : {
      "deal" : "ok",
      "feedback" : "none",
      "user" : ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee2a8")
  },
  "seller" : {
    "deal" : "none",
    "feedback" : "none",
    "user" : ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee8bf")
  },
  "post" : ObjectId("5abf4eb433063a3ebc8ba78f"),
}

// (BEFORE) Offer that i should reject
[{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ad2ab39b0ef21131439223d"),
  "buyer" : {
    "deal" : "none",
    "feedback" : "none",
    "user" : ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee2a8")
  },
  "seller" : {
    "deal" : "none",
    "feedback" : "none",
    "user" : ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee8bd")
  },
  "post" : ObjectId("5abf4eb433063a3ebc8ba78f"),
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ad2b9b2751c39321c4173e4"),
  "buyer": {
    "deal": "none",
    "feedback": "none",
    "user": ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee2a8")
    },
  "seller": {
    "deal": "none",
    "feedback": "none",
    "user": ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee8aa")
    },
  "post": ObjectId("5abf4eb433063a3ebc8ba78f"),
}]

// (AFTER)
[{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ad2ab39b0ef21131439223d"),
  "buyer": {
    "deal": "rejected",
    "feedback": "none",
    "user": ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee2a8")
  },
  "seller": {
    "deal": "none",
    "feedback": "none",
    "user": ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee8bd")
  },
  "post": ObjectId("5abf4eb433063a3ebc8ba78f"),
},
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ad2b9b2751c39321c4173e4"),
    "buyer": {
      "deal": "rejected",
      "feedback": "none",
      "user": ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee2a8")
    },
    "seller": {
      "deal": "none",
      "feedback": "none",
      "user": ObjectId("5abf3c2fb9709a31244ee8aa")
    },
    "post": ObjectId("5abf4eb433063a3ebc8ba78f"),
  }]
```

Comment: This would probably be a much clearer question if you showed the data you need to update and what you expect to happen. Providing some data so that people viewing can reproduce the issue and the solution is usually a better way to present your problem than simply talking about it.

Comment: You cannot call `update()` like that after a populate. What I asked of you is to "show the documents" in the state they would be in and then what you expect to change in them after update. That makes things a lot clearer than attempting to present code that simply will not work.

Comment: ok, sorry, i'll try to update it with some sample docs

Comment: Hello @NeilLunn i've added some sample data on it. hopefully it helps ;) i'll provide more if its not enough

Comment: So I take it the things you want to "update" are actually in the other collection. That's really what we need to see since "updating the content" does not change the reference in the parent. Please show those ones and what you expect to change. As in what is in those ones "before" the change and what happens "after".

Comment: More to the point, do you at least have the `_id` of the offer you want to accept in the request? Seems like you should have that and the user id as well.

Comment: yes i do have the req.user._id = John's ID and req.body.postId = the selected post. I also added the before and after of the data that i need

Comment: You are still really unclear on what the state of the data is "before" the update. I see `deal: "ok"` and `deal: "none"` but what are they before they are rejected? And the **offerid**` is actually the most important thing here for the one you want to accept. Is that in the `req.body` or `params`? I get you want different updates, but you need to be clear about the "what" and "how".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something like this

```
Offers.update({
  "buyer.feedback": "none",  
  post: req.body.postId      //query
}, {
  '$set': {
    'buyer.feedback': 'ok'    // update operation
  }
})
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much, so dumb of me that i never thought about this method. I dont need to query the users model to get the list of offers for the specific post id, i could've just query the Offers model that only points to a specific post and do the updating there. Thanks so much man

Comment: @John yes because `.populate().update()` doesn't make sense... great efforts... cheers

Comment: i'll have myself learn more about mongoose. thanks again man!